# Bash ignoring newline character

Tags: bash

Easiest to explain with some code:

```
body=''
NEWLINE=$'\n'

for name in $names # don't worry about the names array
do
    body+="$name ${NEWLINE}"
done
```

The output is something like this:

```
Joe Michael Tony Peter
```

Why isn't it like this?

```
Joe 
Michael 
Tony 
Peter
```

This should work, as the newline is wrapped in single quotes, but it is ignored.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You don't show enough code to reproduce. How do you generate the output? Unquoted, perhaps?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ah! You are right. It is the echo which is messing things up, not how I am generating the string. Thanks. I'll add an answer for others in case they come across this while Googling.

Comment: `names` might be an array, but `$names` is equivalent to `${names[0]}` in that case. Are you sure you actually *have* an array, or just a  newline-delimited string?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Benjamin W. for pointing me in the right direction.

My issue isn't how I generate the string (that's correct), it's how I'm outputting the string.

This won't work:

```
echo $body
```

But this will:

```
echo "$body"
```